# ".yml" file "prefix" question (How to Implement Yolo V3 Object Detection on Windows with GPU)

Tags: python, windows, anaconda, object-detection, yolo

*(This is my 1st attempt with Anaconda / Python / YOLO / Object Detection)*

I follow [this](https://youtu.be/Y73SWT79Rck) YouTube tutorial.
(as said from time-tag 2:00) I downloaded `Anaconda Python 3.7.3`, copied `yolo.yml` from the [tutorial repository](https://github.com/reigngt09/yolov3workflow/blob/master/2_YoloV3_Execute/yolo.yml) to `C:\yolo\`, & run `conda create env -f yolo.yml`. Until here: OK.

But, at this point, I realized that the last line in `yolo.yml` file is: `prefix: C:\Users\Ritesh\Anaconda3.1\envs\yolov3`. The first line is: `name: yolov3`.

My computer `C:\Users\` folder has `Amit` folder (my name) and not `Ritesh` and, as it seems, `conda create env -f yolo.yml` created the env under `C:\Users\Amit\Anaconda3\envs\yolov3\`.

**Shortly, my question is:** What is the meaning/purpose of the `prefix` line? How it comes to play? Do I have to fix something at this point? & if the answer is YES, than how do I do it?